# On an Excel pivot table, is there a way to apply different filters for each column

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table that I have to change the filters 6 times to get all the totals I need. Can I sum each column based on unique filters for each column?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy and paste the PivotTable 5 times, and change the filters on the other ones to get what you need. Or use the GETPIVOTDATA function to reference the 6 parts of a master pivottable that you want values for.